# Count number of words match in phrase

Tags: r, tm, stringr

I have two big list of phrases. I need to check the percentage of words exist in the other list and get best result out of other list.

```
A <- data.frame(name = c(
  "X-ray right leg arteries",
  "x-ray left shoulder",
  "x-ray leg arteries",
  "x-ray leg with 20km distance"
), stringsAsFactors = F)

B <- data.frame(name = c(
  "X-ray left leg arteries",
  "X-ray leg",
  "xray right leg",
  "X-ray right leg arteries"
), stringsAsFactors = F)

fuzzy_prep_words <- function(words) {
  words <- unlist(strsplit(tolower(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", words)), "\\W+"))
  return(words)
}

fuzzy_prep_words(A$name)
fuzzy_prep_words(B$name)
```

I am able to extract the words from the list but not able to calculate the number and proportion of words matched in the other list.

"X-ray right leg arteries" has exact match in B so it should return two columns - Match : ""X-ray right leg arteries" and Distance = 100%. For second phrase -   "x-ray left shoulder", it should return match - "X-ray left leg arteries" and distance 66.67% as 2 words matched out of 3 words in "x-ray left shoulder". For 3rd phrase, it should return any of "X-ray left leg arteries", "X-ray right leg arteries".

I have already explored string distance algorithms such as LV, COSINE, LCS so I don't want to use it as I have big phrases in my real dataset.

Comment: You could try splitting each string at the space, then use `intersect` to obtain matching sets of words.

Comment: I am able to split string as shown in the post but not able to proceed. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: `intersect(fuzzy_prep_words(A$name), fuzzy_prep_words(B$name))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
m <- lapply(strsplit(tolower(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", A$name)), " "), function(w1)
    do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(strsplit(tolower(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", B$name)), " "), function(w2) {
        cbind.data.frame(
            matches_string_from_B = paste(w2, collapse = " "),
            percentage = sum(w1 %in% w2) / length(w1) * 100)
        }
    ))
)
names(m) <- tolower(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", A$name));

m;
$`xray right leg arteries`
    matches_string_from_B percentage
1  xray left leg arteries         75
2                xray leg         50
3          xray right leg         75
4 xray right leg arteries        100

$`xray left shoulder`
    matches_string_from_B percentage
1  xray left leg arteries   66.66667
2                xray leg   33.33333
3          xray right leg   33.33333
4 xray right leg arteries   33.33333

$`xray leg arteries`
    matches_string_from_B percentage
1  xray left leg arteries  100.00000
2                xray leg   66.66667
3          xray right leg   66.66667
4 xray right leg arteries  100.00000

$`xray leg with 20km distance`
    matches_string_from_B percentage
1  xray left leg arteries         40
2                xray leg         40
3          xray right leg         40
4 xray right leg arteries         40
```

Explanation: Split entries from `A$name` into words, calculate percentage of matching words from split entries from `B$name`, and store in list of `dataframes`. Use `toupper` and `gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", ...)` to make matching case insensitive and ignore punctuation characters.

### Update

To get the best match (percentage-wise) you can do:

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(m, function(x) x[which.max(x$percentage), ]))
#                              matches_string_from_B percentage
#xray right leg arteries     xray right leg arteries  100.00000
#xray left shoulder           xray left leg arteries   66.66667
#xray leg arteries            xray left leg arteries  100.00000
#xray leg with 20km distance  xray left leg arteries   40.00000
```

Comment: Wow, It's great. How can I get best percentage match from each phrase and store it in dataframe consisting phrase_A column against match_B and percentage columns

Comment: @john Please take a look at my updated answer; I've added how to extract the best match per entry from `A$name`.